# Meteor stop subscription if change route

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have two routes with two templates. In one of them, the user subscribe to a collection after clicking a button.

```
 'click #play' : function() {

    Meteor.call('create_game', this._id, function(error, result){
      Meteor.subscribe('game', result);
     });
 }
```

What I want to perform is to stop the subscription if the user change route. I could have used the function waitOn of Iron-Router, then the subscription will be cancelled if the user changes route but I want to start the subscription only if the user click not if he just routes.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Meteor.subscribe`, you get a subscription handle as the return value. This handle has a `stop()` method that you can call whenever you want to stop a subscription. So what you probably want to do is save this handle somewhere and call it when the route changes:

```
handle = Meteor.subscribe(...);
```

In an Iron Router callback:

```
handle.stop();
```

Comment: Where do you save it? I tried to save it with a session variable, Session.set('s', handle) and then Session.get('handle').stop() returns undefined is not a function

Comment: I don't think you can store objects in the session, just data. can you store in a variable of the template?

Comment: Not really, I want to stop it on a different template than the one I started it.

Comment: If you declare a top level variable without the 'var' keyword, it will be visible from all of your files. You cant use Session to store the handle because Session can't store functions.